# flatbuffers: Using add_myTable(table) to encode data

Tags: c++, flatbuffers

I am trying to use the following method of building a table, as taken from the flatbuffers tutorial:

```
MonsterBuilder monster_builder(builder);
monster_builder.add_pos(&pos);
monster_builder.add_hp(hp);
```

But having done this for my root table I am unsure if I need to call `.Finish()` before adding it to the table that then contains the table above.

Is anyone able to provide me with an example of how usage of the `add_member` commands may be used in nested tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `.Finish()` on any tables you create with a table builder. You call `.Finish(root)` on your `FlatBufferBuilder` instance only once at the end to finish construction of the buffer.